# Extension RangeAttribute is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes

I have the following attribute:

```
[ExRequired("PleaseInsert", "LyingPulse")]
[ExRange(40, 150)]
[LayoutAttributes]
public int LyingPulse { get; set; }
```

in Extension Range class:

```
public class ExRange : RangeAttribute
{
    public ExRange(int minLen, int MaxLen) : base(minLen,MaxLen)
    {          
        ErrorMessage = "testRange";
    }


}
```

it's not working  ? what's the problem?

Comment: What's not working exactly? Do you need to do something different from the default `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Range()` validation? If so, are you overriding the `IsValid()` method?

Comment: if is out of range it's not display any error  supposed to display "testRange" , no i not overriding the isvalid() i don't think should to override it

Comment: Where are you trying to display the message? Do you have a `@Html.ValidationSummary()` in your (Razor) view, for example? Put a breakpoint on `ErrorMessage = ...` to make sure it's getting hit. If it is, then it's probably a case of the error message not knowing where to render. Another thing: if the behaviour is no different than that of `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Range()`, why not just do this: `[Range(40, 100, ErrorMessage = "TestRange")]`?

Comment: i use multilanguage so i want to return appropriate ErrorMessage , yes it's contain  html.validation summary all validation  works except  ExRange i use other Extension like ExRequired and it's working

Comment: Have you tried adding a breakpoint on `ErrorMessage = ...` to see if it's getting hit? I don't see why the above wouldn't work. Regarding being multi-language - if you're using .resx files, you can add the localised error message like so: `[Range(1, 2, ErrorMessageResourceName = "OutOfRangeMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorStrings))]`. If you don't already know that, of course :)

Comment: yes i tried add breakpoint and it's getting hit ,  no i not use resx files :(

Comment: What value are you trying to validate exactly? `ExRequired` will be processed first and then `ExRange` will validate that the inputted value is within range.

Comment: For Example: if i add range attribute without extension for some fields so it's will work , when i press on submit button while the field is out of range  it's display message like that: "Please enter a value greater than or equal to 80" but when i use Exrange attribute it's not working !

Comment: Guessing the range for both `Range()` and `ExRange()` is exactly the same? Looking at the display message above, '80' is within `[ExRange(40, 150)]`. Without seeing more of your code, it's very difficult to say why it's not working for you. I've tried it locally (using exactly as above) and it works for me. Perhaps check the ModelState to see if the error is there (`foreach (ModelState modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values) ...`).